# Application Error: net:ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED error after generating Signed APK Ionic4

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic4

I had successfully generate signed APK for Ionic in Android using Android Studio. But when I try to open the app it shows

> ```
> Application Error
> net:ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED
> (http://localhost:8100/)
> ```

Where I am doing the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

replace the web-view plugin `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview version 2`, with `version 1.2.1` The commands I used where these:

> cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
>
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@1.2.1
>
> ionic cordova platforms